# How to find files which have been modified in the last 50 days?

Tags: linux, find

How can I find all the files which have been modified 50 days before?

I'm trying this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime -50
```

is it the right command to find files that have been modified in the last 50 days?

Comment: I removed the request to send the answer to the OP's  email address - that's not how SO works.

Comment: Note that `Linux` is just the kernel, what matters here is the utilities shipped with the system. That will be different if that Linux kernel is in a Debian, OpenWRT, Android or ChromeOS system for instance. The "Linux" tag is generally not useful if the question is about a command.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - thanks for taking that out.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-type f` if you only want regular files. If on a GNU system, the `-printf` predicate can show you the date.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -50 -printf "%T+ %p\n"
```